# Python requests using a proxy returns 'service not known, socket.getaddrinfo, socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] on a valid url

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, python-requests, dns, rhel

**Error:**

> Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not
> known
> File "/***/***/****/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
> for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
> File "a", line 745, in getaddrinfo
> for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
> socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

This problem is only happening on Redhat 7 in production. I have the exact same code running on ubuntu from a different network and I have no problems. Everything works perfect.

My code calls 3 API's. 2 do not work on redhat but one does.
I am using an anonymous proxy.
The other strange thing is I can telnet to all theses api's on redhat through the same proxy and they work fine. But just not through requests.

> UPDATE: the server is on a corporate network which does not resolve dns. The dns is resolved on the external proxy

To me it seems as though the requests library is not communicating with an updated dns resolver or something like this, but I am a bit hazy on dns to be honest.
I don't think there is any point in posting the code as I said it all works perfect on ubuntu.
Just for the sake of It I will post one of the calls.
I am using ...
requests==2.25.1
Python 3.6.12
Redhat 7

```
        HTTP_PROXIES={'http': 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080'}
        headers = {'accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
        data = json.dumps({"key":list_values})

        response = requests.post('https://someapiaddress.com/', 
        proxies=HTTP_PROXIES, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Any help , very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was very simple in the end.
The reason one api worked and the other didn't work was because the API that worked  was non secure http and the ones that didn't work were secure: https
Solution was.
instead of...

`HTTP_PROXIES={'http': 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080'}`

It should have been

```
 HTTP_PROXIES={'http': 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080','https': 'https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080'}
```

Comment: `HTTP_PROXIES` is a dict, which couldn't contain the same key.

Comment: Yes youre right. Sorry that was a typeo. the second key should be https. I updated the answer.